# How to collect rows in a batch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a table that looks like this:

| `id` | `values` |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `a` |
| `2` | `b` |
| `3` | `c` |
| `4` | `d` |
| `5` | `e` |
| `6` | `f` |

and I need to generate group_id column to be able to collect rows in a batch using

```
select collect_list(values) from table group by group_id
```

For example, for batchSize = 2

| `id` | `values` | `group_id` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `a` | `1` |
| `2` | `b` | `1` |
| `3` | `c` | `2` |
| `4` | `d` | `2` |
| `5` | `e` | `3` |
| `6` | `f` | `3` |

to get it out:

| `group_id` | `collect_list(values)` |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `[a, b]` |
| `2` | `[c, d]` |
| `3` | `[e, f]` |

or, for batchSize = 3

| `id` | `values` | `group_id` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `a` | `1` |
| `2` | `b` | `1` |
| `3` | `c` | `1` |
| `4` | `d` | `2` |
| `5` | `e` | `2` |
| `6` | `f` | `2` |

out

| `group_id` | `collect_list(values)` |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `[a, b, c]` |
| `2` | `[d, e, f]` |

How do I generate this column group_id so I can collect the values and group by group_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use row_number and DIV to generate group_id

To expand my answer, we use the Integer division properties to get group id

Row_number will give consecutive Numbers from 1 to N

But we need the numbers to start with 0, so we subtract 1 of the row number

```
rownumber   Div (3)
0           0
1           0
2           0
3           1
4           1
5           1
6           2
```

This can be proven to be true for all integers to infinity

As group_id must start with 1(not necessary actually) we need to add anither 1 to the result

After with the resulting Group-id you can `collect_list(values)` tpo get your arrays

```
SELECT
id, `values`,
((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDEr By id) -1)  DIV 3) + 1 group_id
FROM tab1
```

| id | values | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | c | 1 |
| 4 | d | 2 |
| 5 | e | 2 |
| 6 | f | 2 |
| 7 | g | 3 |
| 8 | h | 3 |
| 9 | i | 3 |

```
SELECT
id, `values`,
((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDEr By id) -1) DIV 2) + 1 group_id
FROM tab1
```

| id | values | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | c | 2 |
| 4 | d | 2 |
| 5 | e | 3 |
| 6 | f | 3 |
| 7 | g | 4 |
| 8 | h | 4 |
| 9 | i | 5 |